# Responsive grid based on viewport size using minmax()

Tags: html, css, css-grid

What I am trying to do, using CSS only and ideally without media queries, is create a grid that is always `100%` of the viewport whereby:

1. the number of rows and columns is determined by the size of the viewport and the following criteria
2. a cell's height or `width` is never less than `180px` unless the viewport's height or width is less than `180px`, in which case the row or column and thus the cell would be all of the available space (e.g. if the viewport's height and width were `150px` by `400px`, then the grid would have 1 row with a height of `150px` and 2 columns; if the viewport's height and width were `400px` by `200px`, then the grid would have 2 rows and 1 column)

```
viewport: 150px height
          400px width
1 row: 150px
2 columns: each 200px
+-------+-------+
|       |       |
+-------+-------+

viewport: 400px height
          200px width
2 rows: each 200px
1 column: 400px
+-------+
|       |
|       |
+-------+
|       |
|       |
+-------+
```

3. a cell's height or width is never more than `359px`
4. therefore, a cell's height or width would be responsive between `180px to 359px`
5. new rows and columns should be added every time the viewport increases by `180px` in whichever direction

Below are some attempts that obviously do not work for one reason or another.

```
html, body, #grid { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

#grid {
  grid-template:
    repeat(minmax(1, calc(100vh / 180px)), minmax(180px, minmax(1fr, 359px))) /
    repeat(minmax(1, calc(100vw / 180px)), minmax(180px, minmax(1fr, 359px)));
}

#grid {
  grid-template:
    repeat(auto-fit, minmax(180px, minmax(1fr,359px))) /
    repeat(auto-fit, minmax(180px, minmax(1fr,359px)));
}
```

**Is it possible with pure CSS and no media queries? If so, how?**

Cells will contain `img` elements with `object-fit: cover`. What I am really trying to do is avoid having really small areas of an image displayed as the viewport and thus the rows and or columns shrink. Another approach would be to use JS to increase the area of cells that contains an `img` as the viewport gets smaller (i.e. as the viewport gets smaller, make an `img` span more rows or columns). Intuitively, I feel as if this would be a better approach.

Comment: you cannot do this `calc(100vh / 180px)` dividing with a unit

Comment: @TemaniAfif omg i was just looking up your username so that i could tag you haha. can we switch `calc(100vh / 180px)` to `100vh / 180px` or is no math permitted at all? if no math is permitted, any idea how to accomplish this with media queries, even if it is hacky or hack-ish?

Comment: @BrettDonald `img` with `object-fit: cover` will be placed in each cell. what i am really trying to do is avoid having really small areas of an image displayed as the viewport is shrunk. another approach would be to use JS to change the cells which an `img` consumes as the viewport gets smaller (i.e. as the viewport gets smaller, make the first `img` span more rows or columns)

Comment: But what are you going to put **into** the grid? With those specifications your grid will have a variable number of cells. How will your application manage that? You'll still have a vertical scroll, I presume?

Comment: @BrettDonald i am using JS to assign a fixed number of `img` items to a "random" area of the grid; see my previous response to your comment that you deleted

Comment: @TemaniAfif i updated the question and added more context at the bottom in response to Brett's question

Comment: I still don't quite understand the design. You say you will have a fixed number of images. Let's say that number is 10. So then If your grid is rendered into a viewport which only has room for 2 cells, what happens to the other 8 images? What if your grid is rendered into a viewport with room for 35 cells, what happens to the 25 cells which don't contain an image?

Comment: @BrettDonald in the case of 2 cells, the other 8 images would not be rendered or assigned. if the grid has 35 cells, you can `span` the 10 images across rows and columns so that the grid appears completely full. (fwiw right now, i will be able to choose the fixed number of images in any case). i now believe the best approach is to simply create a grid of fixed cells (e.g. 12 x 12) and then manipulate the `span` of each image so that the images reflect the cell constraints in my question instead of constraining the cells themselves. does any of this still not make sense?

Comment: I'd be heading for Javascript and absolute positioning to achieve something like that. And you'd have to recalculate everything if the viewport size changes. With rate limiting/debouncing as well.

Comment: @BrettDonald why do u think debouncing is necessary? like, in which circumstances? when the viewport size is near a threshold and could go one way and then back quickly?

Comment: Because if you resize a browser window by dragging a mouse cursor, the resize event will fire many times in rapid succession.

Comment: i see. i would def use `matchMedia()` in the callback

Comment: It is unclear to me if you want a grid of only two cells or if there can be numerous cells. If the latter, what should happen when the viewport is not large enough to fit all of the cells? Do you actually want all of the cells to shrink to fit within the dimensions of the viewport instead of overflowing with a scrollbar?

Comment: @TimR that was just a simple diagram to help clarify to readers what id written. the grid would always be `100%` with `overflow: hidden` as mentioned in the very first sentence

Comment: @TemaniAfif moving `calc(100vh / 180px)` to a variable doesnt even work. any idea on how i might be able to achieve this?

Comment: Regarding the calculation: a value cannot be divided by a length (anything with a unit). Furthermore, the value for the number of columns must also be a number, not a length. Regarding the layout: If the cells are allowed to wrap into columns or rows, the cells will always be the maximum size, unless there is only one row or column and the viewport is narrower than that maximum dimension. If you use `auto-fit` to set the repeat count, you may only specify track sizes using the [<fixed-size>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat#fixed-size) type, not the <track-size> type.

Comment: @TimR thats useful info. thanks <3 so i guess, if we try to accomplish this without JS, there is no way to do it without media queries, eh?

Comment: I played around with this for an unreasonable amount of time. I am convinced that what you desire cannot be achieved using only CSS without media queries.

Comment: @TimR haha ive wasted prolly too much time on this already too. im most likely gonna write it using media queries. appreciate the effort brother